# The form isn't submitting on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When the information is put in and submitted the page is redirected and to shipping screen and keeps doing this unless you refresh the page. I want the information to be submitted and to navigate to the payment screen without having to reload the page. Is there any way to fix?
ShippingScreen.js

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userInfo) {
      navigate("/signin?redirect=/shipping");
    }
  },[userInfo,navigate]);
  
  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    ctxDispach({
      type: "SAVE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS",
      payload: {
        firstName,
        lastName,
        address,
        city,
        states,
        postalCode,
        country,
        location: shippingAddress.location,
      },
    });
    localStorage.setItem(
      "shippingAddress",
      JSON.stringify({
        firstName,
        lastName,
        address,
        city,
        states,
        postalCode,
        country,
      })
    );
    navigate("/payment");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    ctxDispach({ type: "SET_FULLBOX_OFF" });
  }, [ctxDispach, fullBox]);
```

Here is the form that was asked for in the comments. It contains all of the information and the submit button. I'm adding details because it won't let me post otherwise for whatever reason

```
return (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
        <title>Shipping Address</title>
      </Helmet>
      <CheckoutSteps step1 step2></CheckoutSteps>
      <div className="container small-container">
        <h1 className="my-3"> Shipping Address</h1>
        <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label> First Name </Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              value={firstName}
              onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
              required
            ></Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>Last Name</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              value={lastName}
              onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)}
              required
            ></Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>Address</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              value={address}
              onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
              required
            ></Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label> City </Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              value={city}
              onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}
              required
            ></Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>State</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              value={states}
              onChange={(e) => setStates(e.target.value)}
            ></Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label> Postal </Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              value={postalCode}
              onChange={(e) => setPostalCode(e.target.value)}
              required
            ></Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label> Country </Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              value={country}
              onChange={(e) => setCountry(e.target.value)}
              required
            ></Form.Control>
          </Form.Group>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <Button
              id="chooseOnMap"
              type="button"
              variant="light"
              onClick={() => navigate("/map")}
            >
              Choose Location On Map
            </Button>
            {shippingAddress.location && shippingAddress.location.lat ? (
              <div>
                Lattitude: {shippingAddress.location.lat}
                Longitude: {shippingAddress.location.lng}
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div>No Location</div>
            )}
          </div>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <Button variant="primary" className="cusButton" type="submit">
              Continue
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What is the issue here, that you cant submit the form as per the headline or that you gets redirected back and forth from /payment?

Comment: What does  ctxDispach do, can we get to see the state, reducer and bit more relevent code, so that we get a better idea

Comment: I updated the code to add the form